# Where does the indicated negative voltage terminal lie on this circuit?

Tags: voltage, schematics

[image: See the indicated negative terminal]

Does the negative voltage terminal lie after the 150v source ?

Comment: what does this mean? `after the 150v source`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between the 9 ohm resistor and the 150v source